# Prove stabilizer is a group of automorphisms.

Tags: linear-algebra

For v e V, define the stabilizer of v in G to be G subscript v= {a e G |a(v)=v}. Is this necessarily a group of automorphisms of V?

I know that the stabilizer consists of all the permutations of G that send x to itself and that automorphisms are an isomorphism from an object to itself.

My issue is mathematically proving the question. I have no background and proofs and little back ground in linear/abstract algebra. How would you set this up and/or prove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF...$G = GL(V)$, and you actually meant $G_v = \text{Stab}(v)$ (because I don't know where $c$ comes in), then $G$ is already a group of (linear) automorphisms of $V$, so all you have to do is prove $G_v$ is a SUBGROUP.

So if $Av = v$, and $Bv = v$, then you must show $(AB)v = v$, and that $A^{-1}v = v$.